# Addicted to Sounds

Tags: sound-effects

I was mussing about in the studio with a friend of mine a few weeks ago and discovered a way of making really cool and totally epic sweeps using a thin piece of MDF board and the metal edge of a baffle.  Since then I've used it in pretty much everything I've put my ears to since then.  Transitions and flybys.  Ambiences and spot effects.  I just can't help it.  I love the sounds so much, and they [magically] seem to suit everything.

I think I'm approaching the point of beating a severely dead horse, but I can't help myself.  So, how do you guys feel about re-using sounds from project to project?  Do you have a point where you force yourself to stop using certain sounds because you're starting to repeat yourself, or do you just have at 'er and use it till you lose it?

Comment: @g.a.harry, would you care to post a sample of your sound? I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Slightly beside the point, but nice sound!

Comment: @James Thanks.  I've got a series of about 30 of those.  They're so magical, with a bit of filtering and effects they work over everything.

Answer (score 2):

I certainly do that.

I have some whooshes that I built with a combination of [Michael Raphael's rockets](http://rabbitearsaudio.com/rea001-rockets/) and some flame bys that I still use in just about everything.  I need to make some different ones. :)

ditto with some screen text scanning that I did a while back and some other clicky sounding things that work well in UI looking CG moves.

I'm currently in the process of beating to death a recording of our garage door that I made as well.  Its soo big!

Comment: @rene your undying love for my rocket library just warms my heart.

Comment: They make me want to find a rocket society in this part of the world.  :)

Comment: @rene don't tell anyone but there might be a second round of these . . .   shhhhhh